# Passing object from one window to an existing one

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I'm still new in Java, and I have a problem with passing objects between two windows in [JavaFX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX).

I have mainStage with mainStageController. There are two things inside the controller: a label and a button. The button is opening a new window (childStage) with childStageController.

In childStageController I have a method, which gets the text "TEST CONTENT" from textField. I want to pass this text to the existing mainStage and set the label text to "TEST CONTENT".

There are a lot of topics handle similar problems, but in every case I found, the problem is with passing the object to a new created window. My case is exactly the opposite: I need to pass the object from the new opened window to the existing one.

```
@FXML
private Label label;

@FXML
private Button button;

private void configureButton() {
    button.setOnAction(event -> {
        newStageOpener(mainPaneResource, mainPaneStageTitle);

        // There is magic to do

        label.setText(message);
    });
}

private void newStageOpener(String resource, String stageTitle){
    try {
        Parent parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(resource));
        Scene scene = new Scene(parent);
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle(stageTitle);
        stage.showAndWait();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I try to do something like this, but every time I get a NullPointerException (the debugger says that childStageController is null).

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(childPaneResource));
ChildStageController childStageController = loader.getController();
String message = childStageController.getMessage;
```

I also try: using setLocation, using loader.load(), "reverse" problem (setText directly from childStageController, instead of getting it from mainStageController), put newStageOpener into a configureButton, but nothing works - I always get the same NullPointerException.

What should I do to fix it?

Comment: [edit] your question and post the stack trace of the `NullPointerException` you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

There was mistake in newStageOpener - I rebuild it like this:

```
private void newStageOpener(String resource, String stageTitle) {
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(ChildStageController.class.getResource(resource));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle(stageTitle);
        stage.showAndWait();
        getObjectFromResource(resource, loader);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void getObjectFromResource(String resource, FXMLLoader loader) {
    loader.setLocation(ChildStageController.class.getResource(resource));
    ChildStageController childStageController = loader.getController();
    message = childStageController.getMessage();
}
```

getMessage obviously is getting text from TextField.

Now it's working perfect.

Comment: your getObject.. looks fishy: a) setting the location of an already loaded fxmlLoader will throw (afair) - probably not doing here because it's the same b) grabbing the controller from an fxmlLoader only makes sense if it has loaded - in sum, both lines are fighting with each other in the general case.

Comment: Yeah, it's true, but... I had to do that. If not, I get an error "Location is not set", so I have to set location. If I set location and don't load controller - controller is null. I don't know why, but it works only with these lines.